# Android button onClick changing activity cause app to crash in these code

Tags: java, android, xml

**MainActivity**

This is the main activity for java. This activity contains the constructor.
It does not work properly in the on create method:

```java
    package com.example.add;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText edittext1, edittext2;
    private Button buttonSum;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        buttonSum = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name=edittext1.getText().toString();
               String age=edittext2.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (age), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //if(name!=null && age!=null){
              //  int age=Integer.parseInt(edittext2.getText().toString());
               // String a=String.valueOf(name);
             //   int b= Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(age))));

                //DBConnect connect= new DBConnect();
                new DBConnect(name,age);
              // connect.insert(name, age);
               //connect.getData();//}else
                //{System.out.println("Error: data not find");}
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

**DBConnect.java**

```java
     package com.example.add;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import java.sql.*;


    public class DBConnect extends AppCompatActivity implements insert {
    //private Connection con;
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;


    public DBConnect(String name,String age) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    //}
    // public void insert(String x, String y) {
        try {
           // String age = y;
           // String name = x;

            String insert = "insert into person set age='" + age + "',name='" + name + "';";
            st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(insert);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }


    private void getData() {
        try {
            String query = "select * from person";
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println("Records from database");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String Sr = rs.getString("id");
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                String age = rs.getString("age");
                //System.out.println("Srno.: "+Sr+" "+"Name: "+name+" "+"Age: "+age);
                //String sum=;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(Sr), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    }
```

```
**AndroidMainfest.java**
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.add">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>

    </manifest>
```

```
**Activity_main.xml**
```

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.843"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.15" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.843"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.285" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.317" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="136dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:text="Age:-"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.045"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.325" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="146dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:text="Name:-"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.167"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`enter code here`
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.235" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post stack trace.

Comment: There is not stacktrace and the code is not readable(needs to be formatted)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

Button on click listener write like this

```
buttonSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = edittext1.getText().toString();
                String age = edittext2.getText().toString();
                if (name != null && age != null) {
                     new DBConnect(name, Integer.parseInt(age));
              }
          }
     });
```

And `DBConnect()` method like this

```
public DBConnect(String name,int age) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
            st = con.createStatement();
            String insert = "insert into person set age='" + age + "',name='" + name + "';";
            st = con.createStatement();
            st.executeUpdate(insert);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Make sure the connection is made to insert record.